# Error using \toprule \midrule from Booktabs package

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am trying to use the package booktabs to make my tables look nicer. However,
Latex gives me an error whenever I use \toprule \midrule or \bottomrule. Here is a simple
example I created:

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=12,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs} % To thicken table lines

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \topline
    Header 1 & Header 2\\
    \midline
    Body 1 & Body 2\\
    Body 3 & Body 4\\
    \bottomline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the latex output:

http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=367245&c=7201095

I also browsed to `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/` to check if the package is really there. And it is. I cannot see why latex is throwing these errors. Can anyone help?

Comment: As you write in the title, the commands are `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`, not the `\topline`, `\midline` and `\bottomline` that you're using in the table.

Comment: Why is this closed? I'm having the exact issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: You might be here looking for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94846/147162) answer regarding `\toprule` undefined control sequence.

Answer (score 11):

Change `\topline` to `\toprule`, and same with mid and bottom counterparts.

Comment: oh gosh. that worked. I found that example online in a forum and guessed it was working. So I looked for the error at my site. Many thanks. It looked like missed the forest for the trees...