# Problems with \toprule and \midrule in a table

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

Having the following `siunitx` table code in LyX, for each occurrence of `\toprule` and `\midrule` I obtain an error message:

> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message
>   was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `hobx'), type `I'
>   and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

I correctly imported `siunitx` in the preamble.
TexLive version: 2012.10.20121205_r28449.fc18

LaTeX code:

```
\centering
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{tabular}{ccS}
\toprule
{Dimensione finestra} & {Perdita} & {Tempo}\\
{} & {} & {(secondi)}\\
\midrule
10                & 0$\%$       & 121\\
\midrule
10                & 10$\%$       & 127\\
\midrule
10                & 20$\%$       & 176\\
\midrule
10                & 30$\%$       & 257\\
\midrule
10                & 40$\%$       & 442\\
\midrule
10                & 50$\%$       & 780\\
\midrule
10                & 60$\%$       & 1226\\
\midrule
10                & 70$\%$       & 1469\\
\midrule
10                & 80$\%$       & 1904 \\
\midrule
10                & 90$\%$       & 3234 \\
\midrule
50                & 0$\%$        & 46 \\
\midrule
50                & 10$\%$       &109 \\
\midrule
50                & 20$\%$       &146 \\
\midrule
50                & 30$\%$       &202 \\
\midrule
50                & 40$\%$       &257 \\
\midrule
50                & 50$\%$       &373 \\
\midrule
50                & 60$\%$       &544 \\
\midrule
50                & 70$\%$       &760 \\
\midrule
50                & 80$\%$       &1356 \\
\midrule
50                & 90$\%$       &6588 \\
\midrule
100                & 0$\%$       &76 \\
\midrule
100                & 10$\%$       &91 \\
\midrule
100                & 20$\%$       &109 \\
\midrule
100                & 30$\%$       &146 \\
\midrule
100                & 40$\%$       &180 \\
\midrule
100                & 50$\%$       &297 \\
\midrule
100                & 60$\%$       &414 \\
\midrule
100                & 70$\%$       &585 \\
\midrule
100                & 80$\%$       &1355 \\
\midrule
100                & 90$\%$       &4326 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please include your preamble, so other people can try to compile your example. My guess is you need to load the `booktabs` package as well.

Comment: \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

Comment: Thank you Psirus, it worked \usepackage{booktabs}   If you put an official answer I can give you the mark

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`\midrule` is a command defined by the [Booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package. Include `\usepackage{booktabs}` in your preamble to typeset your table.

Comment: So is `\toprule`, which is what was giving me a similar error (`Undefined control sequence`).

Answer (score 30):

Adding

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

solved the problem :O

Answer (score 14):

You should certainly load the `booktabs` package in order to enable the use of `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`.

You should also aim to improve the readability of the table. You could start by getting rid of all interior `\midrule` statements, which add lots of visual clutter without making the table easier to read. In addition, do consider (a) adding a bit of whitespace after the end of 10th and 20th row by inserting an `\addlinespace` statement, (b) formatting the entries in the first two columns more elegantly by assigning them type `S` instead of `c`, and (c) moving the shared `\%` elements from the cells in the second column to the corresponding header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\centering
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.0] 
                S[table-format=2.0] 
                S[table-format=4.0]}
\toprule
{Dimensione finestra} & {Perdita} & {Tempo}\\
{} & {(\%)} & {(secondi)}\\
\midrule
10                & 0        & 121\\
10                & 10       & 127\\
10                & 20       & 176\\
10                & 30       & 257\\
10                & 40       & 442\\
10                & 50       & 780\\
10                & 60       & 1226 \\
10                & 70       & 1469 \\
10                & 80       & 1904 \\
10                & 90       & 3234 \\
\addlinespace
50                & 0        & 46 \\
50                & 10       &109 \\
50                & 20       &146 \\
50                & 30       &202 \\
50                & 40       &257 \\
50                & 50       &373 \\
50                & 60       &544 \\
50                & 70       &760 \\
50                & 80       &1356 \\
50                & 90       &6588 \\
\addlinespace
100                & 0        & 76 \\
100                & 10       & 91 \\
100                & 20       &109 \\
100                & 30       &146 \\
100                & 40       &180 \\
100                & 50       &297 \\
100                & 60       &414 \\
100                & 70       &585 \\
100                & 80       &1355 \\
100                & 90       &4326 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The following screenshot shows the `tabular` environment *with* the proposed modifications on the left, and *without* the modifications (i.e., what would result just from loading the required `booktabs` package) on the right. Note, inter alia, the better centering of the numbers in the third column, which was achieved by specifying `S[table-format=4.0]` instead of just `S`.

I hope you will agree that the table on the left is more readable than the one on the right.

[image]